# Chromecast for digital signage

Tags: chromecast

I was hoping that someone with chromecast experience could help me with the following.

I want to make a simple digital signage application using chromecast. My plan is to set up a bunch of monitors with chromecast attached. Each monitor would point to a particular URL on the local network -- not a public facing web site. Each one would refresh its view every few minutes, completely replacing its content with the information on the web server.

I'd like to do this without mirroring, so that the chromecast itself would keep reloading the page without another device helping it along.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far and are running into any issue? At the end of the day, Chromecast is showing a web page so reloading its url is like any standard browser.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe start with the Chromecast developer guide: https://developers.google.com/cast/ 
From here you could choose to use the API here: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/downloads
When you're ready to release it you probably need to register an API key with them for your sign app here: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/registration
Good luck with your app.

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of it, [Greenscreen.io](http://greenscreen.io/) would be perfect for this application. Especially when you're running a local server.

I want to do a similar digital signage app, but ended up needing to go for Raspberry Pi's with wifi that connect to a public webpage. I'd have preferred to use Chromecast for it though!